# For Python numpy.unique(ar, return_index=False) - indexes of unique are returned in the natural order ALWAYS?

Tags: python, numpy

In Python numpy:
indexes returned by np.unique(a, return_index=True) - will ALWAYS come in natural order ?
I.e. we get the FIRST occurrence of element as first index ? Or the order can be arbitrary ?

In most examples I tried - the order is natural, but just want to confirm it is ALWAYS the case ?

Example:

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
u, indices = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
```

```
array([0, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the function's [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) of return values:

> **unique_indices** ndarray, optional
>
> The indices of the **first occurrences** of the unique values in the original array. Only provided if return_index is True.

So yes, you get first occurrence of elements.